# jQuery: Hiding button until last dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Beginner Coder here, I'm trying to make a web scheduler through my school's Schedule API, so we have a bunch of dropdowns that build into one another (Term, School, Subject, Class, Section). Until the last dropdown has a selection (we have a select button that saves sections into cookies and routes the next dropbox), we want to hide an "Add" Button we're trying to figure out with jQuery.

Unfortunately, it's not working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addButton').hide();
    if ($('#sectionSelect').value() === '') {
      $('#addButton').hide();
    } else {
        $('#addButtton').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

We saved the values of our section dropdowns through cookies (because its variable on routing via APIs),  so would the $('#sectionSelect').value have to be referenced from the cookies?

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to post something on jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

You have a jQuery error:

```
//This is wrong:
$('#sectionSelect').value()

//This is right:
$('#sectionSelect').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

you want the show/hide logic to trigger every time the select button is changed. So something like this will probably work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sectionSelect').change(function() {
      $('#addButton').hide();
      if ($('#sectionSelect').val() === '') {
        $('#addButton').hide();
      } else {
          $('#addButtton').show();
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select").change(function() {

    var selected_val = $("select option:selected").val();
    var last_val = $("select option:last-child").val();

    if (selected_val === last_val) {
      $("#addButton").hide();
    } else {
      $("#addButton").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id="first" value="1">1</option>
  <option id="second" value="2">2</option>
  <option id="third" value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button id="addButton">ADD</button>
```